# Unity cannot find System.Data

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

i am struggling with the System.Data that cannot be found by Unity. Every time i try to use the reference System.Data in my code, here is the error that i get:
"The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System'. (are you missing 'System.Data assembly reference?)
[here is a screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09X9Q.png)

i have seen solutions of this problem here in this site, i tried all of them but i still get the same error. Please i need your assistance. thank you.

Comment: Can you please list the things you've already tried?

Comment: Hi, i tried  to add the .dll file of System.Data in the reference . To do so, i went  to the following  directory: Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0 and get the System.Data.dll file. But Unity still showing the same error.

Comment: Hi, i figured out my problem, i did not put the System.Data inside my Assets folders, that is why i had this problem. Thank you guys though.